# The product of countable spaces which have countable dense subset has a countable dense subset.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a product of countably many spaces $X_{i}$ which have countable dense subset. Prove that $X$ has a countable dense subset.

Comment: I am trying to prove that the product of the denses it is dense in $X_{\alpha}$, but the question is... it is countable?

Comment: The product ot the dense sets is not in general countable.

Comment: sorry ... I've done the proper fix ..

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$, where each $X_n$ has a countable dense subset $D_n$, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $d_n$ be a point of $D_n$. Let

$$D=\left\{\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n:\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\ne d_n\}\text{ is finite}\right\}\;.$$

Prove that $D$ is a countable dense subset of $X$. (Note that $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n$ is **not** countable if infinitely many of the sets $D_n$ contain more than one point.)

Comment: In fact $d_n$ could be any point of $X_n$, we don't gain anything from requiring it to be in $D_n$.

Comment: @Hagen: In a wider context we do gain just a little: $D$ becomes a $\sigma$-product of the sets $D_n$, and $\sigma$-products are well-studied.